# sql server calculation of columns from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select s.part_no
    ,s.part_name
    ,s.uom
    ,i.Invoice_Quantity
    ,r.Return_Quantity
    ,p.Issue_Quantity
    ,sr.Quantity
    ,rp.Return_Quantity
    ,er.Quantity 
from dbo.dri_Stock as s 
left join 
(
    select part_no,sum(Invoice_Quantity) as Invoice_Quantity 
    from dbo.dri_InwardEntry 
    where month(_date)=6 and year(_date)=2012 
    group by part_no 
) as i 
    on s.part_no=i.part_no
left join 
(
    select part_no,sum(Return_Quantity) as Return_Quantity 
    from dbo.dri_ReturnToCustomer 
    where month(date)=6 and year(date)=2012 
    group by part_no
) as r 
    on s.part_no=r.part_no 
left join 
(
    select part_no,sum(Issue_Quantity) as Issue_Quantity 
    from dbo.dri_IssueToProd 
    where month(date)=6 and year(date)=2012 
    group by part_no
)as p 
    on s.part_no=p.part_no 
left join 
(
    select part_no,sum(Quantity) as Quantity 
    from dbo.dri_ShortReceipt 
    where month(date)=6 and year(date)=2012 
    group by part_no
)as sr 
    on s.part_no=sr.part_no 
left join 
(
    select part_no,sum(Return_Quantity) as Return_Quantity  
    from dbo.dri_ReceiptFromProd 
    where month(date)=6 and year(date)=2012 
    group by part_no
)as  rp 
    on s.part_no=rp.part_no 
left join 
(
    select part_no,sum(Quantity) as Quantity 
    from dbo.dri_ExcessReceipt 
    where month(date)=6 and year(date)=2012 
    group by part_no 
)as er 
    on s.part_no=er.part_no 
where i.invoice_quantity>0
```

I want to add a columns in my output i.e **stockBalance**

how can I do this:

Formula for calculating StockBalance will be **(i.Invoice_Quantity + rp.Return_Quantity + er.Quantity) - (r.Return_Quantity + p.Issue_Quantity + sr.Quantity)**

Comment: by the way how is the performance on this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add you calculation to the select.  I would add an `ISNULL` around each of the values in case they are null due to your left joins.

```
select s.part_no,s.part_name,
    s.uom,i.Invoice_Quantity,
    r.Return_Quantity,
    p.Issue_Quantity,sr.Quantity,
    rp.Return_Quantity,er.Quantity,
    ISNULL(i.Invoice_Quantity, 0) + ISNULL(rp.Return_Quantity, 0)
        + ISNULL(er.Quantity, 0)) - (ISNULL(r.Return_Quantity, 0)
        + ISNULL(p.Issue_Quantity, 0) + ISNULL(sr.Quantity, 0)) AS StockBalance
from dbo.dri_Stock as s
left join (
    select part_no,sum(Invoice_Quantity) as Invoice_Quantity
    from dbo.dri_InwardEntry
    where month(_date)=6 and year(_date)=2012
    group by part_no ) as i on s.part_no=i.part_no
left join (
    select part_no,sum(Return_Quantity) as Return_Quantity
    from dbo.dri_ReturnToCustomer
    where month(date)=6 and year(date)=2012
    group by part_no) as  r on s.part_no=r.part_no
left join (
    select part_no,sum(Issue_Quantity) as Issue_Quantity
    from dbo.dri_IssueToProd
    where month(date)=6 and year(date)=2012
    group by part_no) as p on s.part_no=p.part_no
left join (
    select part_no,sum(Quantity) as Quantity
    from dbo.dri_ShortReceipt
    where month(date)=6 and year(date)=2012
    group by part_no) as sr on s.part_no=sr.part_no
left join (
    select part_no,sum(Return_Quantity) as Return_Quantity
    from dbo.dri_ReceiptFromProd
    where month(date)=6 and year(date)=2012
    group by part_no) as  rp on s.part_no=rp.part_no
left join (
    select part_no,sum(Quantity) as Quantity
    from dbo.dri_ExcessReceipt
    where month(date)=6 and year(date)=2012
    group by part_no ) as er on s.part_no=er.part_no
where i.invoice_quantity>0
```

Comment: Thank you mr norlando for help.My query is working fine.